# How to use spreadsheets.readonly instead of the full read/write auth scope

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am creating a web app for my organization using google apps script. The apps functionality boils down to reading data from different sheets and displaying it to the user.

The docs for using the SpreadsheetApp service seems to require that you provide the full r/w scope just to open a sheet; either by ID or URL i.e. openById() or openByURL() requires:

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

However I would like to only use the following scope.

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

I feel like it should be easy to do this in Apps Script but I cannot find anything in the documentation regarding it.

I have found something related to what I want [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get). However this seems very complicated requiring to manage API keys.

Is there a 'simple' read-only interface Google Apps Script provides or am I required to port my project over to a standard google cloud project, enable the Sheets API, figure out API keys, and understand how to apply oauth scopes separate from the appsscript manifest?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether my proposed answer is your expected `a 'simple' read-only interface Google Apps Script provides`, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that the Advanced google services were available at a syntax level. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any documentation for the advanced services API. Specifically I want to know how error handling is done. Is it an Error js object or does it return null, .etc

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, it seems that there is no official document of Sheets API of Advanced Google service while there is [the official document of Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest). So, in this case, I'm using Sheets API of Advanced Google service by checking the official document of Sheets API. I apologize for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, when the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` is required to be used. It seems that this is the current specification. For example, when DriveApp is used before, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` was required to be used. But, by the update on the Google side, when `DriveApp.getFiles()` is used, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` can be used. So, I think that the situation of the Spreadsheet service might be changed in the future update.

But, in the current stage, it is required to use the current specification. So, it is required to use a workaround. In this answer, I would like to propose a workaround for using Spreadsheet with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`.

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare a Google Apps Script project.

Please create a new Google Apps Script project. In this case, you can use both the standalone type and the container-bound script type. In this answer, I would like to use the standalone type. If you want to directly create it, please access https://script.new. By this, you can see the script editor of Google Apps Script. Please set the filename.

#### 2. Enable Sheets API.

In order to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`, Sheets API is used. So, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

#### 3. Prepare manifest file.

Before the script is used, please set the manifest file (`appsscript.json`). So, please show the manifest file. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#editing_a_manifest)

And, please add your expected scope as follows. You can see that Sheets API has already been included in `enabledAdvancedServices`. Please add `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"]` as follows.

```json
{
  "timeZone": "###",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"]
}
```

#### 4. Prepare sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to your script editor and please set `spreadsheetId`, and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

  const res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId);
  console.log(res);
}
```

- About "Method: spreadsheets.get", this is from your question.

#### 5. Testing.

When you run `myFunction`, the script is run. And, the values of the Spreadsheet are returned. By this, you can retrieve the values from Spreadsheet using Sheets API with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`.

### Note:

- The scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` can be used for retrieving the values from Spreadsheet. When you want to update the Spreadsheet, it is required to use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`. Please be careful about this.

### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)